# Entity Framework Transaction not rolling back

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, transactions

The following code is in a loop which executes many times. When I execute the following code it occasionally generates a foreign key exception, which is fine because it is handled and I attempt to role back the transaction. However, on the next run through it generates the same exception and does so over and over again even though the data is correct.

We have a singleton class that stores the context:

```
public class MyDatabaseContext
    {
        private static MyDatabaseContext _instance;

        public static MyDatabaseContext_Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new MyDatabaseContext();
                }

                return _instance;
            }
        }

        public MyEntities Context;


        private MyDatabaseContext()
        {
            Context = new MyEntities();
        }
    }
}
```

Cut down version of main part of the loop:

```
MyEntities entities = MyDatabaseContext.Instance.Context;

// Begin new transaction
entities.Connection.Open();
DbTransaction transaction = entities.Connection.BeginTransaction();

try {

    // Inside the update, we modify some data and call saveChanges() on the same
    // database context, see below
    dataObject.Update()

    // do more stuff to data here

    if (dataObject.isValid())
    {
        transaction.Commit();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // Rollback transaction
    transaction.Rollback();
} fincally {
    entities.Connection.Close();
}
```

This is the Update() method and where it causes the exception

```
public static Update() {
    // get same database context
    MyEntities entities = MyDatabaseContext.Instance.Context;

    // Update data, wont show here, but a foreign key is set to 0 which 
    //will cause an exception

    entities.saveChanges() // Exception thrown here! 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL doesn't support nested transactions. Most probably you are already in transaction, so Begin / Commit / Rollback are **logical** transactions rather than **physical** database transactions.

Try to inspect it using SQL Profiler to see what actually happens.

Simple (but not the best of course) solution is that any time you do `Rollback` you actually need to close connection and start over again.